# How to publish UWP app alongside Windows 8.1 app?

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, uwp

I have a Windows 8.1 app (already published in the Windows Store) that I want to port to a Universal Windows app. Will I have to publish the Universal version separately, or can I somehow merge the two as one published app that runs on both Windows 10 and Windows 8.1?

Comment: AFAIK you need to publish packages separately. When building UWP apps for Windows 10, there is no support for Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 have different SDKs (and project types) so you'll have to publish 2 different packages to the store. You can however add the new Windows 10 package to your existing Windows 8.1 published package. This will allow existing users to upgrade from the old to the new app fluently.

This [publishing process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/guidance-for-app-package-management#adding-packages-for-windows-10-to-a-previously-published-app) is completely described on MSDN, but in short: Create a new submission and add your UWP .appxupload package(s) during the Packages step.

> **Note** The version number of your Windows 10 packages must be higher
>   than those for any Windows 8, Windows 8.1, and/or Windows Phone 8.1
>   packages you are publishing (or packages for those OS versions that
>   you have previously published) for the same app.

Comment: Some windows 8.1 devices cannot be upgraded to windows 10. So if I want to support both Windows 8.1 and 10, does that mean I will have to do something like have all Win 8.1 builds have numbers 1.x.x.x and all Win 10 builds have something like 3.x.x.x ? So then if a Win 8.1 device is updated to 10, then it should automatically get the correct build ?